# Error using .so library inside android application

Tags: android, sdk, android-ndk, shared-libraries, audio

I am trying to use a .so library (http://illiri.com/api.html) inside my android application. I have copied the .so files in libs folder (libs/armeabi, libs/armeabi-v7a, libs/mips, libs/x86), and loading libraries as,

```
System.loadLibrary("crypto");
System.loadLibrary("ssl");
System.loadLibrary("sapi");
```

But I am getting this error in stack trace.

```
    08-26 11:17:24.677: E/dalvikvm(25747): Could not find class 'com.illiri.sapi.SAPIConnection', referenced from method com.ey.illiritest.MainActivity.onCreate
    08-26 11:17:24.697: W/dalvikvm(25747): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 474 (Lcom/illiri/sapi/SAPIConnection;) in Lcom/ey/illiritest/MainActivity;
    08-26 11:17:24.697: D/dalvikvm(25747): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x000b
    08-26 11:17:24.697: D/dalvikvm(25747): VFY: dead code 0x000d-0030 in Lcom/ey/illiritest/MainActivity;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
    08-26 11:17:24.697: I/dalvikvm(25747): Could not find method com.illiri.sapi.SAPIConnection.suspend, referenced from method com.ey.illiritest.MainActivity.onPause
    08-26 11:17:24.697: W/dalvikvm(25747): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3424: Lcom/illiri/sapi/SAPIConnection;.suspend ()V
    08-26 11:17:24.697: D/dalvikvm(25747): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0005
    08-26 11:17:24.697: D/dalvikvm(25747): VFY: dead code 0x0008-0008 in Lcom/ey/illiritest/MainActivity;.onPause ()V
    08-26 11:17:24.707: I/dalvikvm(25747): Could not find method com.illiri.sapi.SAPIConnection.resume, referenced from method com.ey.illiritest.MainActivity.onResume
    08-26 11:17:24.707: W/dalvikvm(25747): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3423: Lcom/illiri/sapi/SAPIConnection;.resume ()V
    08-26 11:17:24.707: D/dalvikvm(25747): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0005
    08-26 11:17:24.707: D/dalvikvm(25747): VFY: dead code 0x0008-0008 in Lcom/ey/illiritest/MainActivity;.onResume ()V
    08-26 11:17:24.707: D/dalvikvm(25747): Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.ey.illiritest-1/lib/libcrypto.so 0x2afcad60
    08-26 11:17:24.707: D/dalvikvm(25747): Added shared lib /mnt/asec/com.ey.illiritest-1/lib/libcrypto.so 0x2afcad60
    08-26 11:17:24.707: D/dalvikvm(25747): No JNI_OnLoad found in /mnt/asec/com.ey.illiritest-1/lib/libcrypto.so 0x2afcad60, skipping init
    08-26 11:17:24.707: D/dalvikvm(25747): Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.ey.illiritest-1/lib/libssl.so 0x2afcad60
    08-26 11:17:24.707: D/dalvikvm(25747): Added shared lib /mnt/asec/com.ey.illiritest-1/lib/libssl.so 0x2afcad60
    08-26 11:17:24.707: D/dalvikvm(25747): No JNI_OnLoad found in /mnt/asec/com.ey.illiritest-1/lib/libssl.so 0x2afcad60, skipping init
    08-26 11:17:24.707: D/dalvikvm(25747): Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.ey.illiritest-1/lib/libsapi.so 0x2afcad60
    08-26 11:17:24.827: W/dalvikvm(25747): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/ey/illiritest/MainActivity;
    08-26 11:17:24.837: W/dalvikvm(25747): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/ey/illiritest/MainActivity;)
    08-26 11:17:24.837: D/AndroidRuntime(25747): Shutting down VM
    08-26 11:17:24.847: W/dalvikvm(25747): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aacc560)
    08-26 11:17:24.847: E/AndroidRuntime(25747): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
    08-26 11:17:24.937: W/System.err(25747): java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    08-26 11:17:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(25747): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    08-26 11:17:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(25747): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    08-26 11:17:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(25747):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    08-26 11:17:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(25747):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
    08-26 11:17:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(25747):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
    08-26 11:17:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(25747):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
    08-26 11:17:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(25747):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
    08-26 11:17:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(25747):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    08-26 11:17:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(25747):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
    08-26 11:17:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(25747):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    08-26 11:17:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(25747):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    08-26 11:17:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(25747):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    08-26 11:17:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(25747):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    08-26 11:17:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(25747):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    08-26 11:17:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(25747):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:895)
    08-26 11:17:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(25747):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653)
    08-26 11:17:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(25747):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    08-26 11:17:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(25747): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1311]:  1376 cannot locate '__gnu_thumb1_case_uqi'...
    08-26 11:17:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(25747):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:434)
    08-26 11:17:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(25747):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
    08-26 11:17:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(25747):    at com.ey.illiritest.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:167)
    08-26 11:17:24.937: E/AndroidRuntime(25747):    ... 15 more
    08-26 11:17:24.967: W/System.err(25747): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/plog.log (Permission denied)
    08-26 11:17:27.797: I/Process(25747): Sending signal. PID: 25747 SIG: 9
    08-26 11:18:46.837: E/dalvikvm(25943): Could not find class 'com.illiri.sapi.SAPIConnection', referenced from method com.ey.illiritest.MainActivity.onCreate
    08-26 11:18:46.837: W/dalvikvm(25943): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 474 (Lcom/illiri/sapi/SAPIConnection;) in Lcom/ey/illiritest/MainActivity;
    08-26 11:18:46.837: D/dalvikvm(25943): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x001a
    08-26 11:18:46.837: D/dalvikvm(25943): VFY: dead code 0x001c-003f in Lcom/ey/illiritest/MainActivity;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
    08-26 11:18:46.837: I/dalvikvm(25943): Could not find method com.illiri.sapi.SAPIConnection.suspend, referenced from method com.ey.illiritest.MainActivity.onPause
    08-26 11:18:46.837: W/dalvikvm(25943): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3424: Lcom/illiri/sapi/SAPIConnection;.suspend ()V
    08-26 11:18:46.837: D/dalvikvm(25943): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0005
    08-26 11:18:46.837: D/dalvikvm(25943): VFY: dead code 0x0008-0008 in Lcom/ey/illiritest/MainActivity;.onPause ()V
    08-26 11:18:46.847: I/dalvikvm(25943): Could not find method com.illiri.sapi.SAPIConnection.resume, referenced from method com.ey.illiritest.MainActivity.onResume
    08-26 11:18:46.847: W/dalvikvm(25943): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3423: Lcom/illiri/sapi/SAPIConnection;.resume ()V
    08-26 11:18:46.847: D/dalvikvm(25943): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0005
    08-26 11:18:46.847: D/dalvikvm(25943): VFY: dead code 0x0008-0008 in Lcom/ey/illiritest/MainActivity;.onResume ()V
    08-26 11:18:46.877: D/dalvikvm(25943): Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.ey.illiritest-1/lib/libcrypto.so 0x2afcb300
    08-26 11:18:46.877: D/dalvikvm(25943): Added shared lib /mnt/asec/com.ey.illiritest-1/lib/libcrypto.so 0x2afcb300
    08-26 11:18:46.877: D/dalvikvm(25943): No JNI_OnLoad found in /mnt/asec/com.ey.illiritest-1/lib/libcrypto.so 0x2afcb300, skipping init
    08-26 11:18:46.877: D/dalvikvm(25943): Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.ey.illiritest-1/lib/libssl.so 0x2afcb300
    08-26 11:18:46.877: D/dalvikvm(25943): Added shared lib /mnt/asec/com.ey.illiritest-1/lib/libssl.so 0x2afcb300
    08-26 11:18:46.877: D/dalvikvm(25943): No JNI_OnLoad found in /mnt/asec/com.ey.illiritest-1/lib/libssl.so 0x2afcb300, skipping init
    08-26 11:18:46.877: D/dalvikvm(25943): Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.ey.illiritest-1/lib/libsapi.so 0x2afcb300
    08-26 11:18:46.927: D/AndroidRuntime(25943): Shutting down VM
    08-26 11:18:46.927: W/dalvikvm(25943): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aacc560)
    08-26 11:18:46.927: E/AndroidRuntime(25943): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
    08-26 11:18:46.957: W/System.err(25943): java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    08-26 11:18:46.967: E/AndroidRuntime(25943): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    08-26 11:18:46.967: E/AndroidRuntime(25943): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1311]:  1376 cannot locate '__gnu_thumb1_case_uqi'...
    08-26 11:18:46.967: E/AndroidRuntime(25943):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:434)
    08-26 11:18:46.967: E/AndroidRuntime(25943):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
    08-26 11:18:46.967: E/AndroidRuntime(25943):    at com.ey.illiritest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
    08-26 11:18:46.967: E/AndroidRuntime(25943):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    08-26 11:18:46.967: E/AndroidRuntime(25943):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
    08-26 11:18:46.967: E/AndroidRuntime(25943):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
    08-26 11:18:46.967: E/AndroidRuntime(25943):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    08-26 11:18:46.967: E/AndroidRuntime(25943):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
    08-26 11:18:46.967: E/AndroidRuntime(25943):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    08-26 11:18:46.967: E/AndroidRuntime(25943):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    08-26 11:18:46.967: E/AndroidRuntime(25943):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    08-26 11:18:46.967: E/AndroidRuntime(25943):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    08-26 11:18:46.967: E/AndroidRuntime(25943):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    08-26 11:18:46.967: E/AndroidRuntime(25943):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:895)
    08-26 11:18:46.967: E/AndroidRuntime(25943):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653)
    08-26 11:18:46.967: E/AndroidRuntime(25943):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    08-26 11:18:46.987: W/System.err(25943): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/plog.log (Permission denied)
```

I have searched a lot in internet and am yet unable to find a solution. Please help.

Comment: Have you got Java class  com.illiri.sapi.SAPIConnection in your apk?

Comment: @AlexCohn Yes Alex. I have a jar file included in my application, sapi.jar. And I am importing the class as import com.illiri.sapi.SAPIConnection inside my activity;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a toolchain issue (see https://dev.guardianproject.info/issues/229) - a forcing NDK toolchain to 4.4.3 seems to do the job.

Comment: It was a tool chain issue. The api website modified it and its working now.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, whenever we are compiling any native code and generating a *.so file using `ndk-build` command of android ndk, it is specific to a particular toolchain.

Now the libraries that you are downloading and using in your application, may not be build using the toolchains supported by the Android ndk. This is one of the reasons due to which i had got a similar error sometime back, when i had used it in my application.

So try the *.so files generated by a toolchain supported by the android system.

Comment: As I mentioned before, am not creating so files. I got it from the application website

Comment: As mentioned, what i'm telling is the website would have created the so files with a toolchain that is not supported by your device.